# Selectable cells in UITableView with ProMotion

Tags: rubymotion, rubymotion-promotion

I’m getting crazy with Pro Motion table and I cannot find any discussion about this online.

I’m using a PM::TableScreen and I need to have selectable table rows. I manage the raw selection in an array but I don’t know how can I get the cell object to call `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` if is selected or `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` if not selected.

Here is the gist of my screen: I try to intercept the cell passing a value in the arguments (row) but I cannot find a method to get the cell object.

In my original idea the place for the selection is inside my `tapped_cell` method byt maybe there is a better way to manage a multiselection.

[My Gist](https://gist.github.com/robypez/443caefe0152ec0ad463)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to memoize the table data. I've created a pull request with the fix:

https://github.com/robypez/rm_quiz/pull/1

Hard to summarize here, although I know Stackoverflow doesn't like us relying on links.